# jquery custom events attached to show and hide (including children)

Tags: jquery

ok, so I've been working on this for way too long. Please help me understand why it's behaving this way.

I previously posted a question that was similar but not the same here: [jquery custom events attached to .show and .hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709364/jquery-custom-events-attached-to-show-and-hide)

I received a response to that question with some code that worked, but without any explanation.

I have moved on to the next steps in terms of required functionality and the solution provided in that posting does not satisfy these expanded requirements. I am having a load of trouble trying to adapt that code without understanding why it's behaving the way it is.

I want the script to trigger one event when any watched element changes visibility. Whether or not that element is the element who is being explicitly shown/hidden or whether that element has an ancestor that is being shown/hidden.

So if I modify the visibility of a div that contains two other divs that I'm watching, then I'd like each of those two internal divs to trigger an event indicating that their visibility has changed, even though I've called show/hide on the ancestor div.

Ideally, I would like those events to be triggered prior to the callback so that I can execute any impacted code before any changes are apparent to the user.

Sounds simple right.?!?

One of the problems I'm noticing is that the two examples are behaving differently. The manipulation of 'question2' doesn't seem to trigger 'madeHidden' at all. The two examples behave differently.

Here's the code I have so far which is not working.
Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hiddenBefore;
    var visibleBefore;
    function processRadioButtonASD1() {
        var isChecked = ($("input[name='question1']:checked").val() == "question1.Vermont");
        if (isChecked == true) {
            $("[data-uniquename='question2']").show(250);
        } else {
            $("[data-uniquename='question2']").hide(250);
        }
    }
    function watchVisibilityChange(uniqueName) {
        $("[data-uniquename='" + uniqueName + "']").bind("madeVisible", function () {
            alert($(this).attr("data-uniquename") + " was made visible");
        });
        $("[data-uniquename='" + uniqueName + "']").bind("madeHidden", function () {
            alert($(this).attr("data-uniquename") + " was made hidden");
        });
    }
    function processRadioButtonASD2() {
        var isChecked = ($("input[name='question5']:checked").val() == "question5.Vermont");
        if (isChecked == true) {
            $("[data-uniquename='c']").show(250);
        } else {
            $("[data-uniquename='c']").hide(250);
        }
    }
    $(function () {
        $.each(["show", "hide"], function () {
            var _oldFn = $.fn[this];
            $.fn[this] = function () {
                var _name = $(this).attr("data-uniquename");

                hiddenBefore = $(this).parent().find(":hidden");
                visibleBefore = $(this).parent().find(":visible");

                var result = _oldFn.apply(this, arguments);

                //trigger handler on newly visible elements                    
                hiddenBefore.filter(":visible").each(function () {
                    $(this).triggerHandler("madeVisible");
                });

                //trigger handler on newly hidden elements
                visibleBefore.filter(":hidden").each(function () {
                    $(this).triggerHandler("madeHidden");
                });
                return result;
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {

        watchVisibilityChange("question2");
        watchVisibilityChange("c.question6");
        watchVisibilityChange("c.question7");

        processRadioButtonASD1();
        processRadioButtonASD2();

        //hook up behavior to the appropriate change events
        $("input[name='question1']").change(function () {
            processRadioButtonASD1();
        });
        $("input[name='question5']").change(function () {
            processRadioButtonASD2();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the html.

```
    <div runat="server" id="promptContent">
    <div id="radioButtonASD" class="oneExample">
        <h2>
            radio button trigger one</h2>
        <div data-uniquename="question1" class="question">
            <label for="question1">
                Question 1) (select Vermont to show question2)
            </label>
            <br />
            <label data-uniquename="question1.Maine">
                <input name="question1" data-uniquename="question1.Maine" type="radio" value="me" />Maine</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question1.Vermont">
                <input name="question1" data-uniquename="question1.Vermont" type="radio" value="question1.Vermont" />Vermont</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question1.NewHampshire">
                <input name="question1" data-uniquename="question1.NewHampshire" type="radio" value="question1.NewHampshire" />New
                Hampshire</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question1.Conneticut">
                <input name="question1" data-uniquename="question1.Conneticut" type="radio" value="question1.Conneticut" />Conneticut</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question1.Massachusetts">
                <input name="question1" data-uniquename="question1.Massachusetts" type="radio" value="question1.Massachusetts" />Massachusetts
            </label>
        </div>
        <div data-uniquename="question2" class="question">
            <label>
                Question 2)
            </label>
            <br />
            <select>
                <option data-uniquename="question2.honda" value="honda">Honda</option>
                <option data-uniquename="question2.volvo" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option data-uniquename="question2.saab" value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option data-uniquename="question2.mercedes" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option data-uniquename="question2.audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cascadingASD" class="oneExample">
        <h2>
            radio button trigger multiple</h2>
        <div data-uniquename="question1" class="question">
            <label for="question1">
                Question 5) (select Vermont to show question6)
            </label>
            <br />
            <label data-uniquename="question5.Maine">
                <input name="question5" data-uniquename="question5.Maine" type="radio" value="me" />Maine</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question5.Vermont">
                <input name="question5" data-uniquename="question5.Vermont" type="radio" value="question5.Vermont" />Vermont</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question5.NewHampshire">
                <input name="question5" data-uniquename="question5.NewHampshire" type="radio" value="question5.NewHampshire" />New
                Hampshire</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question5.Conneticut">
                <input name="question5" data-uniquename="question5.Conneticut" type="radio" value="question5.Conneticut" />Conneticut</label><br />
            <label data-uniquename="question5.Massachusetts">
                <input name="question5" data-uniquename="question5.Massachusetts" type="radio" value="question5.Massachusetts" />Massachusetts
            </label>
        </div>
        <div data-uniquename="c">
            <div data-uniquename="c.question6" class="question">
                <label>
                    Container Question 6)
                </label>
                <br />
                <select>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question6.honda" value="honda">Honda</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question6.volvo" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question6.saab" value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question6.mercedes" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question6.audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div data-uniquename="c.question7" class="question">
                <label>
                    Container Question 7)
                </label>
                <br />
                <select>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question7.honda" value="honda">Honda</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question7.volvo" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question7.saab" value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question7.mercedes" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                    <option data-uniquename="c.question7.audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would really love a solution, but mostly I'd love to know why this isn't working as intended.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I figured it out.
I've definitely grown my understanding, pulled out some hair, and seem to have achieved the behavior I was aiming for.

```
        $.each(["hide"], function () {
        var effect = $.fn[this];
        $.fn[this] = function (duration, move, callback) {
            var speed = duration;
            var easing = callback && move || move && !jQuery.isFunction(move) && move;
            var _mainElement = $(this);
            var _mainElementOriginallyVisible = $(this).is(":visible");
            var _visibleChildrenBefore = $(this).find(":visible");
            return effect.call(this, speed, easing, function () {
                if (_mainElementOriginallyVisible == true) { _mainElement.triggerHandler("madeHidden"); }
                _visibleChildrenBefore.each(function () {
                    if (!($(this).is(":visible"))) {
                        if ($(this).attr("data-un") !== undefined) { $(this).triggerHandler("madeHidden"); }
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    });
    $.each(["show"], function () {
        var effect = $.fn[this];
        $.fn[this] = function (duration, move, callback) {
            var speed = duration;
            var easing = callback && move || move && !jQuery.isFunction(move) && move;
            var _mainElement = $(this);
            var _mainElementOriginallyVisible = $(this).is(":visible");
            var _hiddenChildrenBefore = $(this).find(":hidden");
            return effect.call(this, speed, easing, function () {
                if (_mainElementOriginallyVisible == false) { _mainElement.triggerHandler("madeVisible"); }
                _hiddenChildrenBefore.each(function () {
                    if (!($(this).is(":hidden"))) {
                        if ($(this).attr("data-un") !== undefined) { $(this).triggerHandler("madeVisible"); }
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

The most notable problem I was having with the original code seemed to be regarding the asynchronous animation. My code was executing immediately after triggering the animation, and wasn't waiting for it to finish so the element I just tried to hide, wasn't actually hidden in the subsequent line of code..etc.

I had to leverage the callback parameter to wait for the animation to complete before continuing execution.

This is the code I've arrived at. I'm sure it can be refined. 
**Please don't hesitate to provide suggestions on how to tighten up this code**. 
I'm only a week or so into jQuery and I want to learn.

I recognize there are ways other than show/hide to alter the visibility of elements, and I'm fine with the limitation that those methods must be used to trigger the custom events.
I've also applied an intentional restriction that only items with my custom attribute *data-un* (used to be *data-uniquename*) will trigger the events.

-Todd